# Only Internet Explorer gives error : 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, asp-classic

I working on asp project but when I run this project on internet explorer 8 then it gives following error:

> 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object

```
        if (obj == 18){
            var name18=document.getElementById("infomsg-18");
            if (name18 != null)
            {
                name18.style.display='none';
            }
        }                                   
    }
    else
    {
        //line:285
        document.getElementById('infomsg_rmsg').innerHTML = 'Info:...'+xmlhttp.status;
        //document.getElementById('Divajax').innerHTML = xmlhttp.statusText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","/Reset_ModifFlagSession.asp",false);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: plz post the html too or create a jsfiddle

Comment: Message: 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object
Line: 285
Char: 2
Code: 0

Comment: I don't know if this is a copy/paste error, but the brackets in your example don't match

Comment: yes dude i just copy paste

Comment: can you correct it? It's impossible to follow the program flow like that

Comment: @AnupKaranjkar We don't know which line is 285. You may want to add that somehow...

Comment: The error means there's no element with id `"infomsg_rmsg"` when that script got executed.

Comment: What is in the corresponding if-statement for the else just above line 285?

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos i give comment there //line:285 please check friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Passerby said there is no element with id "infomsg_rmsg" so you can't access the innerHTML property of a null object. If it really does exist (check your source code to confirm) then the reason is probably because you are calling this inline (`<script>...</script>`) BEFORE the DOM has finished loading. Try calling the same function from an `onload` handler and see if it gets detected.

Also I suspect your HTML is probably broken so before you do anything make sure your HTML [validates](http://validator.w3.org).

Finally, on SO you'll get better answers if you write better questions. There is too much missing HTML / script in your question to do anything but guess.